# A question about positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ positive definite matrix and let $0<\lambda_1\leq \ldots\leq \lambda_n$ be $n$ eigenvalues of $A$. Is it true that, for any $x\neq 0$, $x$ must be eigenvector for some $\lambda_{i_0}\in \{\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n\}$, i.e., $Ax=\lambda_{i_0}x$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is an eigenvector? What do the sets of all eigenvectors look like?

Comment: When faced with questions like this, it's usually a good idea to try some simple examples, such as $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ as Aweygan suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.  Let 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then $A$ is positive definite, but
$$x=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\1\end{pmatrix}$$ is not an eigenvector of $A$.
It is true, however, that every $x$ is a sum of eigenvectors of $A$.  This is the context of the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Hermitian_maps_and_Hermitian_matrices).